# <XXX> is not a known element. Please verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, ionic3

I created a module of components and imported it in app.module.ts.

component/component.module.ts:

```
// import stuff........
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ComponentA,
        ComponentB,
        ComponentC
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        PipesModule
    ],
    exports: [
        ComponentA,
        ComponentB,
        ComponentC
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        SearchTabComponent
    ],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        PageA,
        PageB
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { tabsHideOnSubPages: true }),
        IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
        AuthModule,
        HttpModule,
        PipesModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        DirectivesModule,
        IonicImageViewerModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        PageA,
        PageB
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The app is working fine but in the .html part it shows that it is not a part of the module.

Comment: Add this line : `import {ComponentsModule} from './component/component.module';`above the `@NgNodule` in `app.module.ts` file

Comment: I have already imported it in app.module.ts, every thing necessary is imported still it shows the problem mentioned above

Comment: @TejashriPatange im facing a similar issue, were you able to fix this?

Comment: @NivedithaKarmegam nope